# ZF2: Skeleton Application is omnipresent on XAMPP installation

Tags: zend-framework2, xampp

I'm quite new to Zend Framework 2 and ran into an issue I think which is easy to clear but as I'm lacking in knowledge regarding ZF2 I don't know how to tackle the following issue:

I've installed ZF2 with its Skeleton Application on my XAMPP installation in htdocs/zf2, where the applications runs smoothly. However now I want to develop something else in htdocs/dev without any Zend involvement but when I call the PHP file I get the 404 error of the Skeleton Application. How can I tell the Framework that its power is limited to the aforementioned folder htdocs/zf2?

Comment: This is more of an Apache question. Can you provide any info as to how you setup your virtual hosts?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your virtual host for htdocs/dev has the correct doc root in the conf file and the domain is pointing to the right location